# Implementing threads to build Smith-Watermann matrix faster

Tags: c#, multithreading, matrix

I have a problem with the implementation of the threads for the following loop in C#:

```
        for (int i = 1; i < matrix.scoreMatrix.GetLength(0); i++)
        {

            for (int j = 1; j < matrix.scoreMatrix.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                matrix.CalculateScore(i, j);
            }
        }
```

This loop fills the array of matches to Smith Waterman algorithm. It takes a lot of time because I wanted to improve the process of filling in the matrix.

Filling the matrix must be performed from the upper left corner as the following cells are computed on the basis of the cells located above and to the left.

My idea is to take advantage of this 2-3 additional threads that will fill each line array as shown in the picture below:

[image]

Any tips or similar arrangement will be very helpful.

I`v done sth like this:

Main function:

```
        int i = 0, t1_row=0, t2_row=0, t3_row=0, finished_lines=0;

        Thread t1 = new Thread(() => getnext1(matrix, i, t1_row, t2_row, t3_row, finished_lines));
        Thread t2 = new Thread(() => getnext2(matrix, i, t1_row, t2_row, t3_row, finished_lines));
        Thread t3 = new Thread(() => getnext3(matrix, i, t1_row, t2_row, t3_row, finished_lines));

        t1.Start();
        t2.Start();
        t3.Start();
        t1.Join();
        t2.Join();
        t3.Join();
```

Thread functions:

```
    public static void getnext1(SWMatrix matrix, int i, int t1_row, int t2_row, int t3_row, int finished_lines)
    {
        do
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < matrix.scoreMatrix.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                if (t1_row <= t3_row - 1 || finished_lines >= i - 2)
                {
                    matrix.CalculateScore(i, j);
                    t1_row++;
                }
                else
                {
                    j--;
                }
            }
            finished_lines++;
            i++;
            t1_row = 0;
        }
        while (i >= matrix.scoreMatrix.GetLength(0));
    }

    public static void getnext2(SWMatrix matrix, int i, int t1_row, int t2_row, int t3_row, int finished_lines)
    {
        do
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < matrix.scoreMatrix.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                if (t2_row <= t1_row - 1 || finished_lines >= i - 2)
                {
                    matrix.CalculateScore(i, j);
                    t2_row++;
                }
                else
                {
                    j--;
                }
            }
            finished_lines++;
            i++;
            t2_row = 0;
        }
        while (i >= matrix.scoreMatrix.GetLength(0));
    }

    public static void getnext3(SWMatrix matrix, int i, int t1_row, int t2_row, int t3_row, int finished_lines)
    {
        do
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < matrix.scoreMatrix.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                if (t3_row <= t2_row - 1 || finished_lines >= i - 2)
                {
                    matrix.CalculateScore(i, j);
                    t3_row++;
                }
                else
                {
                    j--;
                }
            }
            finished_lines++;
            i++;
            t3_row = 0;
        }
        while (i >= matrix.scoreMatrix.GetLength(0));
    }
```

Query execution time is extended to almost two times. But I also have information that the threads work. How to optimize this code? Any suggestion? I test it on a machine with 4 processor.

Comment: What is your question? Are you asking if this is a valid/safe approach? Are you asking if it will improve performance? Are you asking for teh codez?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I`m interested in answers to all these questions.

Comment: If you do not provide links when you ask for help on specialized/obscure algorithms or data structures, you are inherently limiting the help that you could receive to a small number of specialists who might happen to see this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code as written is not correct. For example: there is a race condition where more than one thread can increment `finished_lines` at the same time and produce the wrong result. Your idea of using static variables to communicate between threads suffers from a problem called [false sharing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc872851.aspx) and will sink performance. [Edit: Looking more closely at your code, I see you're not using shared variables at all. Your code can never work.]

I think you're better off working with blocks or tiles instead of single lines. If your tiles are arranged like this:

```
A B C D ...
B C D E ...
C D E F ...
D E F G ...
. . . . ...
```

then all tiles with the same label (on the same anti-diagonal) can be computed in parallel once all the previous tiles have been computed, and you don't need to worry about synchronizing between threads at all.

This is actually a little bit more restrictive than it needs to be. What you need is a wavefront algorithm. It just so happens that the [Samples for Parallel Programming with the .NET Framework](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Samples-for-Parallel-b4b76364) from Microsoft contains a `ParallelExtensionsExtras` project that includes an efficient implementation of a wavefront algorithm. This uses the Task Parallel Library from .NET 4.0 or higher.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Do you have any links to the methods of implementation of threads using blocks? I do not want to create a new inefficient method. I use framework 4.0 but i have no expiriance with task parallel library. In this case, better to use a task over threads?

Comment: I would highly recommend using the Task Parallel Library. It is much easier to work with. Because the people at Microsoft did the hard stuff, it's easier to write correct code. In the Microsoft sample I linked to, the file `ParallelAlgorithms_Wavefront.cs` contains the code I am talking about.

Comment: I have one more question. Where i should implement my function matrix.CalculateScore(i, j) in Wavefront alghoritm. There is a method processRowColumnCell but i don`t know where exactly put my matrix.CalculateScore method to perform it on each cell.

Comment: Remember we're working on blocks or tiles here. So instead of `CalculateScore(i,j)` we have `CalculateScore(iFrom,iTo,jFrom,jTo)` which in turn should call your `CalculateScore(i,j)`.

Comment: Hey. I don`t know how to do it, i suck. In file ParallelAlgorithms_Wavefront i have two overloads of functions Wavefront. Witch one i have to use? Where i have to put my CalculateScore function in this code? I have to build another overload of my function CalculateScore with 4 int`s and call it in calling of wavefront function?